# Pandas unable to split on multiple asterisk

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to split on 5x asterisk in Pandas by reading in data that looks like this

```
"This place is not good ***** less salt on the popcorn!"
```

My code attempt is trying to read in the reviews column and get the zero index

```
review = review_raw["reviews"].str.split('*****').str[0]
print(review)
```

The error

```
sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat at position 0
```

My expectation

```
This place is not good
```

Comment: Escape the asterisk: `.str.split('\*{5}').str[0]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[pandas.Series.str.split](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)**

> `Series.str.split(pat=None, n=- 1, expand=False)`
>
> Parameters:
> patstr, optional String or **regular expression** to split on. If not
> specified, split on whitespace.

`*` character is a part of regex string which defines zero or more number of occurrences, and this is the reason why your code is failing.

You can either try escaping the character:

```
>>df['review'].str.split('\*\*\*\*\*').str[0]
0    This place is not good 
Name: review, dtype: object
```

Or you can just pass the **regex**:

```
>>df['review'].str.split('[*]{5}').str[0]
0    This place is not good 
Name: review, dtype: object
```

Third option would be to use inbuilt `str.split()` instead of pandas' `Series.str.split()`

```
>>df['review'].apply(lambda x: x.split('*****')).str[0]
0    This place is not good 
Name: review, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

Try out with this code

```
def replace_str(string):
    return str(string).replace("*****",',').split(',')[0]



review = review_raw["reviews"].apply(lambda x:replace_str(x))
```

Well suppose we already have a ',' in our input string in that case the code can be little tweaked like below. Since I am replacing ***** , I can replace with any character like '[' in the modified answer.

```
def replace_str(string):
    return str(string).replace("*****",'[').split('[')[0]



review = review_raw["reviews"].apply(lambda x:replace_str(x))
```

Comment: .str.split('\*{5}').str[0] is definitely the simpler and more effective answer but I appreciate both.

Comment: Yes @anky ..that's a possibility too ..so tweaked the code little bit...

Comment: @BrettLapierre ...u can try with updated script too..It will provide same result

Comment: @Deepak, your code is still going to fail if there is `[` character already in the column, replacing characters like this can not be a robust solution, and can not guarantee to work always. Still if you want to do this with `replace`, try using some `ASCII` with python's `chr` function, for example: `str(string).replace("*****",chr(11)).split(chr(11))[0]`

Comment: @ThePyGuy ..yup your solution is robust one...thanks for suggesting alternative one...It's cool